# Using Pandas to create DataFrame out of complicated dictionary / list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
dictionary = [{
    'vendor': 'vendor1',
    'option_list': [{
        'col1_name': 'Column1',
        'col1_options': ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']
        }, {
        'col2_name': 'Column2',
        'col2_options': ['small']
        },  {
        'col3_name': 'Column3',
        'col3_options': ['yellow', 'black', 'green']
        }
    ]
},  {
    'vendor': 'vendor2',
    'option_list': [{
        'col1_name': 'Column1',
        'col1_options': ['option3']
        }, {
        'col2_name': 'Column2',
        'col2_options': ['small', 'medium', 'large']
        }, {
        'col3_name': 'Column3',
        'col3_options': ['yellow', 'green']
        }
    ]
}]
```

And I want to turn this into a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
Vendor    Column1    Column2    Column3
vendor1   option1    small      yellow
vendor1   option2    NaN        black
vendor1   option3    NaN        green
vendor2   option3    small      yellow
vendor2   NaN        medium     green
vendor2   NaN        large      NaN
```

The issue is, that I don't know how many vendors and columns I will get. Also, some of the inserted data can be NaN as shown in above example.

Is there any way to use pandas to create dataframe out of this kind of dictionary?

Would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a pandas function which can transform this type of dictionary into the wanted dictionary. You have to build intermediate dictionary which can be given to the DataFrame factory and after concatenate them.

The following code should do the trick:

```py
dictionary = [{
    'vendor': 'vendor1',
    'option_list': [{
        'col1_name': 'Column1',
        'col1_options': ['option1', 'option2', 'option3']
        }, {
        'col2_name': 'Column2',
        'col2_options': ['small']
        },  {
        'col3_name': 'Column3',
        'col3_options': ['yellow', 'black', 'green']
        }
    ]
},  {
    'vendor': 'vendor2',
    'option_list': [{
        'col1_name': 'Column1',
        'col1_options': ['option3']
        }, {
        'col2_name': 'Column2',
        'col2_options': ['small', 'medium', 'large']
        }, {
        'col3_name': 'Column3',
        'col3_options': ['yellow', 'green']
        }
    ]
}]

to_concat = []
for one_vendor_dict in dictionary:
    new_option_dict = {}
    for option_dict in one_vendor_dict['option_list']:
        column_name, option_value = None, None
        # get column name and column values
        for k, v in option_dict.items():
            if 'name' in k:
                column_name = v
            if 'options' in k:
                option_value = v
        if column_name and option_value:
            new_option_dict[column_name] = option_value

    # put all list to same length in order to build a dataframe.
    max_length = max([len(v) for v in new_option_dict.values()])
    for k, v in new_option_dict.items():
        if len(v) < max_length:
            new_option_dict.update({k: v + [None] * (max_length - len(v))})
    # add the vendor column
    new_option_dict.update({'Vendor': [one_vendor_dict['vendor']] * max_length})
    # create a dataframe for this vendor
    to_concat.append(pd.DataFrame(new_option_dict))
df = pd.concat(to_concat).reset_index(drop=True)
```

This print:

```
   Column1 Column2 Column3   Vendor
0  option1   small  yellow  vendor1
1  option2    None   black  vendor1
2  option3    None   green  vendor1
3  option3   small  yellow  vendor2
4     None  medium   green  vendor2
5     None   large    None  vendor2
```

If you have more column for one vendor, the `concat` function will fill with `None` or `NaN` when concatenate.

I use `None` because the options are strings but this is correctly detected by the `isna` function if needed after.

Answer (score 3):

Manioulate that in pure python and use some pandas for final adjustments

```
a = [[x['vendor'], vals[f'col{i+1}_options']] for x in d \
                                              for (i,vals) in enumerate(x['option_list'])]

vendors, data = zip(*a)

pd.DataFrame(data)\
  .groupby(list(vendors))\
  .apply(np.transpose)\
  .reset_index(drop=True, level=1)
```

---

```
               3       4       5
vendor1  option1   small  yellow
vendor1  option2    None   black
vendor1  option3    None   green
vendor2  option3   small  yellow
vendor2     None  medium   green
vendor2     None   large    None
```

Comment: Im gonna try out tomorrow. I did one thing that changed the picture here: can we assume that col_name and col_options would be always the same? No need to increment +1

Comment: @PiotrKonopnicki yea, just make `col_options` static intead of a dynamic f-string

Comment: Somehow this code is crashing my kernel on jupyter-notebook-5.7.8 Python 3.7.3  python windows. Any idea?

Comment: @AshutoshParida what you mean by crashing?

Comment: python process terminates. Error on jupyter notebook : The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Tried a different approach, using pandas merge function:

```
import pandas as pd
final_df=pd.DataFrame() # this will have the final data required

# loop thru dictionary and create the dataframe of required columns
for i in range(len(dictionary)):
    df0=pd.DataFrame([dictionary[i]['vendor']],columns=['vendor'])
    df1=pd.DataFrame((dictionary[i]['option_list'][0])['col1_options'],columns=['Column1'])
    df2=pd.DataFrame((dictionary[i]['option_list'][1])['col2_options'],columns=['Column2'])
    df3=pd.DataFrame((dictionary[i]['option_list'][2])['col3_options'],columns=['Column3'])

    # merge the dataframe using outer incase either df is emphasized 
    df_merg1= pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)
    df_merg2=pd.merge(df_merg1,df3,how='outer',left_index=True,right_index=True)

    # this needs to be expanded to fit the max 
    df0=pd.concat([df0]*df_merg2.shape[0],ignore_index=True)

    # this will have the required dataframe vendorwise
    df_merg3=pd.merge(df0,df_merg2,how='left',left_index=True,right_index=True)

    #keep concatenating for the final output
    final_df=pd.concat([final_df,df_merg3],axis=0,ignore_index=True)

#print final output
final_df
```